# ListView Hidding rows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

My requirement is to hide specific rows in a `ListView`. Since there is no inbuilt functionality I was using the `ListView_DrawItem` Event to hide the specific rows. I was able to hide the rows but the issue is there is a balnk space coming if i add a row post to the hidden row.

Please find the below code:

```
ListViewItem LVI = listView1.Items.Add("1");
LVI.SubItems.Add("Srikanth");
ListViewItem LVI1 = listView1.Items.Add("2");
LVI1.SubItems.Add("Suresh"); 

private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.Text != "2")
    {
       e.DrawDefault = true;
    }
}
```

Output Looks Like

1 Srikanth

3 Sandy

Would like to remove the space b/w 1 & 3 record

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are not really hiding the items, that is plain to see.  Instead, you are offering to draw them yourself, and passing some off to default rendering.  The items are there regardless.

My approach would be to manipulate the collection, adding only those items that the list box needs to deal with.

Depending on the data you have at hand, keep a local copy of the full list, in order, such as in a generic `List<YourDataClass>`.  Also, keep a list of 'hidden' indexes.

Respect the order of `List<T>` and loop across it, only adding new `ListViewItem` objects for those indexes *not* present in the 'hidden' list.

```
private List<String[]> _listItems = new List<String[]>();
private List<Int32> _hiddenIndexes = new List<Int32>();

private void UpdateCollection()
{
    listBox.Items.Clear();
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < _listItems.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!_hiddenIndexes.Contains(i))
            listBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem(_listItems[i]));
    }
}
```

Beware that if this happens to be a list with a very large number of items, it might not be the most efficient approach.